# Is Lock-a-Folder a secure and reliable way to encrypt information?

Tags: encryption

What are the properties of Lock-a-folder?

- does it create plain-text temporary files anywhere? (e.g. [ntfs artifacts](http://eraser.heidi.ie/forum/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=5481), etc)
- does it allow running a program from the folder as if it was a normal folder?
- is it easy to backup and restore?
- does it use a well known format that could be decrypted easily via a custom made program? (say if the apocalypse happens and you no longer have the program)?
- other useful info on it?

Basically I want to know if this is a reasonable way to keep my data secure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering that Lock-a-folder is no longer supported by its developers, I would definitely say NO, it is not a safe option for securing data.

> Developer have abandoned this Project and will not reply to any
>   queries. You can use this code at your own risk. Anyone interested in
>   further development of this project can clone or contribute. https://code.google.com/p/lock-a-folder/

You'll be much better off with a more well known file encryption utility, like one of Truecrypt's successors (like https://veracrypt.codeplex.com/) or GPG.